# Running an application as different user

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to run my project as a different user but all the solutions I have seen are for initiation of a process as a different user. I want to hard code the username into the project so that every time the program is being ran it runs as that user. The reason I need this is so that users that don't have privileges on my network to be able to start and stop services on the server.

So I need something like having the username and password securely stored in the program so that every time it runs it runs as that user.

As I previously said all I've found previously is impersonation of a user just to start some external process, but I need it to start with that user.

**EDIT**

I have found the solution to my problem and it's PsExec.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [impersonation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)? (Disclaimer: I wrote the linked article)

Comment: Thank you for the quick respond :) I will have a look at it right away and tell you if that worked for me.

Comment: I looked at the code and the explanation but from what I gather this is only a temporary solution because it will only execute the code that is within the brackets. I need the whole project to be ran as a different user.      
     using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname",     "myPassword" ) )
     {
       ...
       
       <code that executes under the new context>
      
       ... 
    }

Comment: So you need to run your "whole project" using credentials that are contained _within_ the project?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @stuartd
Do you know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are also some other alternatives which can help in achieving this like PsExex Tool.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx

You can provide the required parameters (like username , password ,the process to start) from Process class and it will launch it successfully using those user credentials.

For more Info:-
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/e20ddf85-26ba-45a7-a987-89de076eda23/solved-run-program-as-different-user-through-batch-file?forum=ITCG

E.g. psexec \workstation64 -c test.bat -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

It works in my case without any issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! PsExec is just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new process with different user credential (see: [ProcessStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)). Therfore, one possible solution is, to check if a command line argument was passed to the application (e.g. '/runAsOther'). If not, start the application again in a new process with the desired user and pass the command line argument '/runAsOther'.

**Code Example:**

```
if (!Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("/runAsOther"))
{
    var process = new Process();
    var securePassword = new SecureString();
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "path to you application";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/runAsOther";
    process.StartInfo.Domain = "domainname";
    process.StartInfo.UserName = "username";
    var password = "test";
    for (int x = 0; x < password.Length; x++)
        securePassword.AppendChar(password[x]);
    process.StartInfo.Password = securePassword;
    process.Start();
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

---

> So I need something like having the username and password securely stored in the program so that every time it runs it runs as that user.

Storing the password securely within the application is not possible and not recommend. However, the best thing you could do is to decrypt it with a machine specific algorithm (e.g. using the [DataProtector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotector(v=vs.110).aspx) class).

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as I said in the question I am aware of this but it only runs the application externally I was wondering if there is a way to do write this within the project and upon activation of the exe file of the application it will automatically use the logon credentials for the other user.

Answer (score -2):

You need to change your application pool identity. Go in Advanced, look for identity, select custom account and enter the credentials.

[image]

EDIT: I guessed you were in a IIS senario at first. Since you changed your requirement to WPF, this answer will not work. Please disregard.

Thanks

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is about a WPF application. .NET applications are a bit more than ASP.NET pages in IIS, you know? There's no such thing as a configurable application pool for desktop applications.

Comment: Something like this is exactly what I'm looking for but I'm afraid @ThorstenDittmar is right ... and I need to do this but in code.. I am currently trying to implement a solution that was suggested by but I'm having some difficulties understanding how impersonate works.

Comment: I usually do not guess but ask instead, when things are unclear/ambiguous.